# D3 forced graph dynamically add links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Once I found a D3 graph on the web, where it was possible to click on a node. Afterward, a line with an arrow was attached to the mouse position, and as soon as another node was selected this line and arrow stuck to the second node.

It was a really good way to add dynamic links between nodes. Unfortunately, I can´t find this example any longer. In case any of you bookmarked it, kindly share.

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph

Comment: Unfortunately not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! For those who may need it too.

http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347